# Google Sheets: Formatting a list of timestamped values to a weekly view

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to transform a growing list of timestamps and values to a calendar-style weekly display in Sheets, with only one unique value per day and time of day not important.

I have tried to do this using an INDEX-MATCH for both: the week number and the day of the week, but I'm having trouble debugging it, due to the blank value of cells for future timestamps resolving to "Sat" when using the `text()` function.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(ValuesRange,MATCH(Week,WEEKNUM(TimestampsRange),0),MATCH(Day,text(TimestampsRange,"ddd"),0),),)`

Would appreciate advice for any more expedient formula.

Summary:
I want to go from:

```
+----------------------------+----+
|                            |    |
+----------------------------+----+
| August 23, 2022 17:40:11   | 4  |
| August 29, 2022 11:20:30   | 8  |
| September 4, 2022 15:55:17 | 10 |
+----------------------------+----+
```

To :

````
+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+
|     | Mon | Tues | Wed | ... | Sun |
+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+
| 34  |     | 4    |     |     |     |
| 35  | 8   |      |     |     | 10  |
| ... |     |      |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+```
````

Answer (score 0):

**Paste this formula** and drag down.

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(
              SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(REPT("F,",
              WEEKDAY(A2,3)+1), "(.+).\z"), ".\z",TEXT(B2,"@")),","),"F",""))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the help. This only makes one value per row, I'd like to have the values rendered on the same row, grouped by week number Mon->Sun. Would you have any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Comment: In the end `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$:$B,MATCH(1,($C2=WEEKNUM($A$:$A))*(D$1=text($A$:$A,"ddd")),),))` gave me what I was looking for, but it seems expensive to autofill this for every cell as opposed to one array formula.

Comment: Please include your desired result if it's diffrent than the original one.

Comment: My example includes 2 items on the same row